How to correctly validate a stepper with Yup
I have a question about how to validate a step form correctly with Yup.
I have the following case:


const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  step1: Yup.object().shape({
    origin: Yup.string().required('Required...');
  }),
  step2: Yup.object().shape({
    code: Yup.string().when('step1.origin', (value, schema) => {
      console.log({value}); //  [undefined]
      // if(value === 'XX') ....
    });
  })
})



In the code above I would like to do the validation directly, but I cannot access the value of step1.origin
How I managed to do it, but in a bad way:


let origenValue = null;

const validationStep1 = Yup.object().shape({
  origin: Yup.string().transform((value, originalValue) => {
    // This code is the one I actually used for ORIGIN by the SELECT2 library
    if (originalValue && originalValue.value) {
        origenValue = originalValue.value;
        return originalValue.value;
    }
    return value;
  }).required('Required...')
});

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  step1: validationStep1,
  step2: Yup.object().shape({
    code: Yup.string().when('step1', (_) => {
      return origenValue === 'XX'
        ? Yup.string().required('Required...')
        : Yup.string().nullable();
    }),
  })
})




not so sure but can you please try this approach (replace step2 with this one):
step2: Yup.object().shape({
  code: Yup.string()
 .test('custom-validation', 'error message', function (value) {
    const step1Origin = this.parent.step1.origin;
    console.log("step1Origin",step1Origin);
  })
}) 

